# htmlspecialchars not working

Tags: php, mysql

My code is:

```
$description = $_POST['description'];
$description = htmlspecialchars($description);
```

I use it to insert some description into a table:

```
$insertBillIndexQuery = "INSERT INTO $billIndexTableName (type, exp_category, shopping_date, shop, description, total_amount, paid, due, mode_of_payment) VALUES ('Expense', '$exp_category', '$billDate', '$shop', '$description', '$total_amount', '$paid', '$due', '$modeOfPayment')";
```

This works fine usually. However, when I type a special character such as a single quote, the system breaks, and I get an Error Querying Database error. I'm sure that the single quotes are causing the problem. Am I using `htmlspecialchars` wrong?

Comment: You're assuming that `'` is an html special character; it's not.... but it is in SQL, and needs escaping if it's part of a string value.... learn to use prepared statements, and it ceases to be an issue

Comment: @MarkBaker Can you provide a link to the same? I don't know what it is..

Comment: HTML escaping and SQL escaping are two completely separate things.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the conversion using `ENT_HTML401` for converting `'` into `&#039;`. According to the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

> **`' (single quote)`**
>   `&#039;` (for `ENT_HTML401`) or `&apos;` (for `ENT_XML1`, `ENT_XHTML` or `ENT_HTML5`), but only when `ENT_QUOTES` is set

Comment: Okay.. but after the form submits, the `&#039` value gets saved in the database. How do I output the character `'` instead?

Comment: @SomenathSinha `&#039;` is converted automatically to `'` by the browsers in HTML mode, the same way how `&amp;` gets displayed as `&`.

Comment: In the context of the question - database insertion - this is a pretty horrible answer...

Comment: @jeroen Agreed with you.

Comment: @SomenathSinha The right thing to do is, please use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for the right way.

Comment: @jeroen ^^^^ Updated.